# How to create this 2 layer pie chart in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

[Picture of Pie chart i need to create in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WaUk.png)

Anyone know how to create this in Excel? I'm having trouble

Comment: With a little bit of clever formatting, I think you could create two pie-charts, and just overlay the one on the other.  Then, tweak where the text is.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hmm, would maybe be possible if the "other" slice didn't stick out. Just tried googling mostly, can't find anything on Excel itself.

Comment: Yeah, that little grey line that goes through both would be a tad tricky - just add a portion to each data set that hopefully gets that slice size?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up using this method to create a donut chart instead: http://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/using_pie_charts_and_doughnut_charts_in_excel.html

Comment: "Link Only" answers are generally frowned upon here. If you would like to leave an answer, it's best to leave an explanation & some documentation, because external resources may later become unavailable, rendering the answer useless to future visitors to this question :)